# Does an electron emit light when it falls from a higher energy level to a lower one WITHIN A BAND?

Tags: electronic-band-theory, photoelectric-effect

If so, what determines the associated frequency? And if not, where does the energy go?

Is the existence of energy bands instead of unique energy levels the reason behind metals being lustrous, since the electrons can transition between infinite energy levels thus absorbing and emitting all light that falls on them?

I'm a high school senior, recently introduced with the band theory and photoelectric effect.

Comment: This is a bigger question than you realize.  Short version: no, light is not emitted.  The luster is due to the metal behaving like a conductor, which it does at low frequencies.  This is *plasma* behavior.   The plasma oscillations, like conduction, is associated with INTRABAND transitions. So your intuition about luster is correct, but probably not in the way you are imagining.  Not very satisfying, I know, but maybe these obscure words will help you know where to start looking for more complete description.

Comment: @garyp Okay Could you please elaborate on "The plasma oscillations, like conduction, is associated with intraband transitions" and "which it does at low frequencies?" I tried looking up what I could but couldn't understand half of it. Maybe some simple, intuitive way to know what's really going on?

Comment: 51 minutes since I made the last comment and I (think I) already know a lot more. There's something called 'plasma frequency' which is proportional to (Number of electrons per unit volume of plasma)^1/2. Plasma oscillations occur when an EM wave of a frequency lower than plasma frequency interacts with plasma and these oscillations create another EM wave. Plasma frequency of metals is in the UV (because they have many free electrons contributing to plasma nature) hence they can 'reflect' light of any frequency below it. Can you verify if I'm on the right track?

Comment: Definitely on the right track.